# Are Avatars With Sexual Content Acceptable?

Tags: discussion, profile-picture

I came across a male user who uses an avatar that shows two young women, one  bowing to kiss the cleavage of the other.

Is this kind of content acceptable on StackOverflow? I personally find this bordering on sexism and it may be offensive to some users. We all want StackOverflow to be more welcoming to all users.

If it is not acceptable, that is the proper way to handle situations like this? Report the user? How?

Comment: To flag a "user", just custom flag any post by that user and explain the situation.

Comment: OK, but is it appropriate to flag a user with an avatar like this?

Comment: Personally, I would find the image inappropriate and flaggable. Although I'm not sure what the exact policy is for user profile content.

Comment: Still, your recourse is the same. What's considered acceptable and non-acceptable is fluid, and bound to change along with the community's perceptions. If you find it objectionable, flag it.

Comment: OK, done, I've flagged their post and added a comment asking them to change the picture: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895111/timeout-nodejs-express-https-not-changeable

Comment: The user changed their avatar, I've retracted my flag

Comment: I think the word "sexism" is irrelevant in this context. The goal of the user is obviously not some anti-feminist one, rather to collect hormonally driven upvotes. He doesn't know that having the face photo of 20 yr old girl, he could reach the same. That wouldn't be called "sexually explicit", but he could still get the lot of hormonally driven sympathy upvotes. This is being done by a lot of us, and not even the SE can do anything against it (it would mean that we forbid 20yr old girls from the site which would be hilarious).

Comment: @peterh, not everything is about reputation. Some of the new user see SO as a forum. And use profile picture as a way to show some personality. Car, girl and manga can be expected as profile picture. they are not all evil, some are just young and looking for some social recognition.

Comment: @DragandDrop Also I was 20yr old, far before the existence on the SE. Playing a girl was a known option for all us, but we didn't do, because we found it disgusting. The world went into a bad direction :-(

Comment: @peterh It wasn't "cat fishing". But yeah I'm with you on the "decadent youngth".(Fr:jeunesse décadente, can't find the english idiom for this.) Even if it make us sound like old folks.